# Changing code for 5 class image classifier

Tags: image, keras, classification

I would like to change the code provided here for 5 class of images. What chnages are need to be made.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance
https://github.com/marsbroshok/image-classifier-with-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

NUM_CLASSES = 5, pretty much it